# in python, How do I pass each value of a list seperately as variable lenght arguments in a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to pass each values of a list as separate arguments in a function that accepts variable length arguments(*args) .

When I pass each argument directly it works fine, but when I pass each argument as a separate value of a list, it does not give expected result.

For instance,

```py
def foo(no,*values):
    values=list(values)
    for i in range(0,len(values)):
        values[i]=values[i]*no
    return(values)
print(foo(5,6,7,8,9,10))
```

This works fine and gives me my expected output as:

```
[30, 35, 40, 45, 50]
```

But this does not:

```py
def foo(no,*values):
    values=list(values)
    for i in range(0,len(values)):
        values[i]=values[i]*no
    return(values)
h=[6,7,8,9,10]
print(foo(5,[i for i in h]))
```

This generates following output:
Actual Result:

```
[[6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]]
```

Expected Result:

```
[30, 35, 40, 45, 50]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can unpack lists using `*`:

```py
def myfunc(no, *values):
  ...

arr = [1,2,3,4]
myfunc(5, *arr)  # >>> myfunc(5, 1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Comment: please don't fix the code of the OP like you did here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57496374/8620333 it can be the main issue of the question that you make irrelevant

Comment: because I cannot ping you on the other question.

Answer (score 0):

Because `[i for i in h]` is returning a list: `[6,7,8,9,10]`

and multiplying a list, which you are essentially doing will just append the content of the list to itself.

To get the expected output you have to give your function just the contents of your list, so you can either call it via `foo(5, *[i for i in h])` or just `foo(5, *h)`.

However `foo(5, *[i for i in h])` would be quite unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

When you call the function, you can use `*` operator which will unpack your list:

```py
def foo(no,*values):
    return [map(lambda i: no *i,values)]

foo(5,*[i for i in [6,7,8,9,10]])

#will return [30, 35, 40, 45, 50]
```

In pep-3132 you can find all the use-cases for iterable unpacking: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/