# Changing colors with repeating linear gradient

Tags: html, css

I have some css which donates a repeating linear gradient.

```css
.btn-filled {background: repeating-linear-gradient(
  45deg,
  #606dbc,
  #606dbc 10px,
  #465298 10px,
  #465298 20px
); border: none !important;}
```

```html
<a class="btn btn-lg btn-filled" href="https://adsler.co.uk">Design</a><a class="btn btn-lg btn-white" href="http://4309.co.uk/portraits/">Illustration</a>        </div>
```

[view here](http:///4309.co.uk)

That works, but when I try to change the color, it doesn't

```css
.btn-filled {background: repeating-linear-gradient(
  45deg,
  #e34242,
  #e34242 10px,
  #465298 10px,
  #465298 20px
); border: none !important;}
```

```html
<a class="btn btn-lg btn-filled" href="https://adsler.co.uk">Design</a><a class="btn btn-lg btn-white" href="http://4309.co.uk/portraits/">Illustration</a>        </div>
```

It works here but not on the site. Why not?

Comment: there is no class `btn-btn-filled` but `btn-filled`

Answer (score 1):

This would be the the way to make your css show up. Is this the intended behavior?

```css
.btn-filled {
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(
  45deg,
  #606dbc,
  #606dbc 10px,
  #465298 10px,
  #465298 20px
); border: none !important;}
```

```html
<a class="btn btn-lg btn-filled" href="https://adsler.co.uk">Design</a><a class="btn btn-lg btn-white" href="http://4309.co.uk/portraits/">Illustration</a>        </div>
```

Comment: +3, not quite sure what you mean. Does something need to be fixed?

Comment: @the_legitTDM thanks. So why doesn't it work on my site when I change colors from a purple to red?

Comment: @New do you mean you want the gradient to be two shades of red as opposed to a red and a purple/blue? If so you'd need to change the last 2 hex codes in the class that controls gradient. I have done it here: https://codepen.io/the_legitTDM/pen/aboNbew

Comment: Thanks for that. It's kinda what I meant but I wanted red and yellow....?

Comment: The issue is, it works here and in codepen but not on my site. 4309.co.uk

Comment: I'm not actually seeing the code you have here showing on your site, but here is what you need to do ````background: repeating-linear-gradient( 45deg, #606dbc, #606dbc 10px, #465298 10px, #465298 20px ) !important;```` with whatever colors you want (the colors don't matter).The reason for this is because of this line ````background: #000000 !important;```` if you changed that in your code you wouldn't need the ````!important````